# onchange to input file type works but breaks after 1 time use unless refresh page

Tags: html, forms, sharepoint

I added onchange to input type = file which does work, I originally had a seperate button for upload but I prefer this. However, after I upload the file it reverts the input file type to the default parameters.

```
<table>
<td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" id="attachmentsOnClient" style="width: 424px">
<input type="file" name="fileupload0" onchange='OkAttach()' id="onetidIOFile" size="56" title="Drag files here or click to upload"style="height:100px; width:420px">   </input>
</td>
</table>
```

turns into something like after uploading.

```
<input type="file" name="fileupload0" id="onetidIOFile" size="50" title="name"> </input>
```

refreshing the page brings back original code.

I'd like to keep the input file type with the defined values and not have it revert each time I upload a file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to refresh the value like so: `$('#onetidIOFile').val('');` in jQuery.